# How can I enable tab completion for a fish function/alias?

Tags: unix, autocomplete, fish

Probably easier to just use an example here. I have a function `ss` that just calls:

```
sudo systemctl $argv
```

Tab completion works fine with the full command, but not for the `ss` function. I.e.,

```
ss start mys<tab>
```

tries to complete from the filesystem rather than using the completion function for `systemctl` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some reseach, it seems that there are two upcoming features in fish, neither of which is in the current stable release (2.1.1).

The first is a `--wraps` argument to `function` and `complete`, which enables completion inheritance. `function foo --wraps=bar` gives `foo` all completions registered for `bar`.

The second is abbreviations through the `abbr` command, which work much like vim abbreviations. `abbr -a gco='git checkout'` registers an abbreviation `gco` to expand to `git checkout`. Typing `gco` followed by a space or enter expands the abbreviation, which naturally allows for any registered completion to work.

Without either of these features, the only remaining thing to do is to write a custom completion script for your function/alias, which is silly.

Comment: Both of these features are now a part of fish. Cheers!